# Rails 3 update_attributes for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3.2 console I am trying to update several records to the same value.

For example:

```
h=Person.find_all_by_company_country("Alabama")
```

Now I want to change the company_country to "Texas"

For example:

```
h.update_attributes(company_country: "Texas")
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_attributes' for #<Array:0x00000003b01d70>
```

What are the options to do this?

Comment: Won't that update all the Person attributes. I just want the ones with Alabama to change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
Person.where(company_country: "Alabama").update_all(company_contry: "Texas")
```

See the update all docs here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: This works great. I keep forgetting to try to use where. Thanks

Comment: Anytime! Glad to help.

Comment: NOTE: This does not run the callbacks, including validations, for these records. It's a direct-to-database change. So if you want to ensure validity or if you have an audit trail or something that needs to know when a record changes, don't use this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your method `find_all_by_company_country` to use active record querys instead, so you can return a relation.

```
h = Person.where(company_country: "Alabama")
```

Then simply invoke:

```
h.update_all company_county: "Texas"
```

Note though that update_all does not invoke active record callbacks. If you need callbacks & validations to fire, instead use:

```
h.each { |record| record.update_attributes({ company_country: "Texas" }) }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the output, the result from the `find_all*` method returns an array object, of which doesn't have the `update_attributes` method.

Just as an example, to modify each record of an array, you would iterate each record like this:

```
Person.find_all_by_company_country("Alabama").each do |record|
  record.update(:company_country => "Texas")
end
```

But the typical way is to perform the update with the `where` and `update_all` methods, which is far more efficient by using a single update query:

```
Person.where(:company_country => "Alabama").update_all(:company_country => "Texas")
```